# Expo dev - getting exception Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'

Tags: android, reactjs, expo, native

When i am trying to build my app on expo dev with following command

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
```

if am getting following exception

### FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:33: error: attribute 'android:name' in  tag must be a valid Java class name.
> /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/build/intermediates/packaged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:58: error: attribute 'android:name' in  tag must be a valid Java class name.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================
> 2: Task failed with an exception.

---

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

build should be created